# Toggle off resize option for windows in Mac OSX

Tags: windows, macos, resize

How can I create a window in Mac OsX without the resize button (a fixed resolution window)?

Answer (score 1):

When you programmatically create a window in Cocoa, you do a call like this

```
long mask = NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask;

wnd = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: rect 
                                  styleMask: mask
                                    backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                      defer: NO];
```

Don't add the NSResizableWindowMask flag.
In interface builder, uncheck the Resize property of the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in IB, the attribute is controlled by the "Resize" checkbox of the window attributes of the main window.

I'm not sure how you do it programmatically, but a combination of setContentMaxSize: setContentMinSize and setShowsResizeIndicatotr: might do it.  See the [Window Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SizingPlacingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000228-135785) for more info.